# Is there an error in my matrix proofs (Also: potato quality jpeg errors present)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Disclaimer: The jpg quality of the problem is terrible, ALL SUPERSCRIPT IN BLOCKQUOTES CAN BE INNACURATE.**

> $A\in \Bbb R^{n\times n} $ is symmetric   $B\in \Bbb R^{n\times h}$
>
> $C=A^3-3A^2+2BB^T$
>
> Lets prove $C $ is a symmetric matrix

Then,

> Prove $A$ is invertible and express the inverse in function of $A$ using the following equation:
>
> $A^6-4A^2-2Id=0$

So at first sight the $h$ variable puzzles me, but it's what I see (albeit, barely)... if you guys can make any sense of that then please do, if not, let $n=h$ and we move on.

It seems like you need to have a clear understanding of matrices and symmetric properties for this question. $2BB^T$ is symmetric through properties of transposed matrix multiplication and scalar multiplication of a symmetric matrix, right? Then the multiplication of a identical symmetric matrix by itself is symmetric thus $A^2$ is symmetric. Then I don't even know about the $A^3$ ...(Heck, it could even be a $5$, its really pixelated)

Moving on, to prove the latter is inversible we grab the determinant of both sides, and do some nifty operations to end up with
$$|A^6|=|4A^2|$$
$$|A^6||A^{-2}|=|4||A^2||A^{-2}|$$
$$|A|=^4\sqrt{4}\times1$$

Thus $A $ has inverse which in my belief could be represented as follows.
$$1/2 \left( A^6-4A^2 \right)A^{-1}=A^{-1}$$
$$1/2A^5-2A=A^{-1}$$
I'm thinking that 4 is missing a $n$ exponent but I can't be sure. Any knowledge leading to better understanding of matrix operations is welcome.

Comment: Your solution of the inverse is correct. $h$ need not be $n$. $BB^t$ is a $n$ by $n$ matrix, whatever be the value of $h$.

Comment: $A^3$ is also symmetric: $$(A^3)^T=(A^2A)^T=A^T(A^2)^T=AA^2=A^3$$ The same goes for any other power of $A$ (this shows that the product of two _commuting_, symmetric matrices is symmetric).

Comment: @voldemort Holy moly, I did not see that. However, is it all OK?

Comment: I prefer to think of it like, $A^3=AAA$ so $(A^3)^T=(AAA)^T=A^TA^TA^T=AAA=A^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am perfect.

As for my question regarding $A^3$, Arthur has made clear the proof regarding it's symmetric aspect. He who shall not be named also has an honourable mention for letting me know of the fact $BB^T$ is, contrary to my own belief, a $n\times n$ matrix.